# How to get previous result x2 in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I've a  BeanShell Assertion within a HTTP Request sampler:

[image]

The previous result can be obtained using the script `ctx.getPreviousResult()`, but how can we get the result **before** the previous result?

Comment: E.g. to achieve something alike `if (previousResult.previousResult.getResponseCode().equals("202")) {`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get "older" sample result than previous result is always previous and when next sampler is being executed it's being overwritten by current, etc.

You can use bsh.shared namespace to hold the "interesting" sampler result. In order to do so add [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the sampler, which result you need to store and put the following code into "Script" area:

```
bsh.shared.result = prev;
```

In your Beanshell Assertion you will be able to get response code as:

```
String code = bsh.shared.result.getResponseCode();
if (code.equals("202")) {
    //do what you need
}
```

Demonstration:

[image: bsh.shared.namespace.demo]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](http://How%20to%20Use%20BeanShell:%20JMeter's%20Favorite%20Built-in%20Component) guide for more Beanshell tips and tricks.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? Seems odd that there's no inbuilt mechanism to reference previous results (since results are often interlinked).